# python - problem with output - iterate over dictionary

Tags: python

I want to print('Doesn't exist') when the input is not a key in dictionary, it looks like its checking every single key in dictionary and prints if its there or not. I would like to ask if its possible to get output only one time if  dictionary doesn't' contain input.

```
number = input('Number: ')

data = {
        '1' : 'One',
         '2' : 'Two',
         '3' : 'Three',

        }

number = number.upper()
for a, value in data.items():
    if a == number:
        print(number, ":", value)
    else:
         print('Doesnt exist here')

Number: 1
1 : One
Doesnt exist here
Doesnt exist here
```

Comment: You don't need a loop.  `if number in data: print data[number]`

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you describe. It scans all the items IN the dictionary, therefore they are known to exist. You are checking against a number and for all the items that DO exist you print "don't exit here". The python dictionaries have a built-in  functionality to check whether a key exists. You can use it as **pppery** has suggested. If you want to do the exercise of iterating over a collection you should stop on the fist found item and either keep a flag, or break the code flow (like return from a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible solutions to this problem:

use `in` keyword

```
number = input('Number: ')

data = {
        '1' : 'One',
         '2' : 'Two',
         '3' : 'Three',
}

if number in data:
    print("{}: {}".format(number, data[number]))
else:
    print('Doesnt exist here')
```

OR [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError)

The python dictionaries throws `KeyError` if the key is not in

```
try:
    print("{}: {}".format(number, data[number]))
except KeyError as ex:
    print('Doesnt exist here')
```

OR [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
print(data.get(number, "Does not exist here"))
```

Hope this helps, Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the upper() function. Keys aren't chars.

Comment: Removing the `.upper()` call would not fix the issue mentioned in the question.

Comment: yep! thanks, will remember, I wanted to use it with strings. In this case I have just numbers, so no need to use .upper()

Comment: @pppery Symbols and Numbers are ignored by upper() python function.

Answer (score 0):

So you do not need to use for loop. instead of for loop add this line:

```
print(number, ":", data[number]) if number in data else print("Doesn't exist")
```

also eliminate that upper method since it is ineffective.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
        '1' : 'One',
         '2' : 'Two',
         '3' : 'Three',
}
number = input('Number: ')
str_number = str(number)
if str_number in data:
    print(str_number, ":", data[str_number])
else:
     print('Doesnt exist here')
```